# objectify-appengine - Embedded class - not a supported property type

Tags: java, google-app-engine, entity-relationship, objectify

I am trying out the objectify(version 2.2.3) embedded classes example (wiki) on google app engine. I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: one: com.mypkg.LevelOne is not a supported property type.
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedSingleValue(DataTypeUtils.java:184)
```

The code I have is the same as the one in Wiki. The section in the controller:

```
    EntityWithEmbedded ent = new EntityWithEmbedded();
    ent.one = new LevelOne();
    ent.one.foo = "Foo Value";
    ent.one.two = new LevelTwo();
    ent.one.two.bar = "Bar Value";
```

The EntityWithEmbedded class:

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class EntityWithEmbedded {
    @Id public Long id;
    @Embedded public LevelOne one;
    //getter & setters here
}
```

Class levelOne:

```
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
public class LevelOne {
    public String foo;
    public @Embedded LevelTwo two;
    //getter & setters here
}
```

Class LevelTwo:

```
public class LevelTwo {
    public String bar;
        //getter & setters here
}
```

So it is the basic example that I am trying out. Any ideas on what is missing?

Comment: I already tried using @Entity and @Id on LevelOne and LevelTwo classes. I made the fields public on purpose to avoid getters and setters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong `@Embedded` annotation in `EntityWithEmbedded`.

Use `javax.persistence.Embedded` rather than `javax.jdo.annotations.Embedded`