# Retrieving user object by ID

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, key, google-cloud-datastore

I still can't work with GAE's keys/ids. I keep getting the error: No entity was found matching the key: Key(Medewerker(5201690726760448)). The entities exist in the datastore, I checked this multiple times.

I'm trying to just simply get an user object with a certain ID. In my servlet I have the following code:

```
Long userId = Long.parseLong(req.getParameter("user"));
User user = userDao.getUser(userId);
```

The above code brings up the error. In userDaoOfyImpl.java I have the following method 'getUser':

```
public Gebruiker getGebruiker(Long id) {
    Gebruiker result = null;
    Gebruiker leerling = (Gebruiker) ofy.get(Leerling.class, id);
    Gebruiker medewerker = (Gebruiker) ofy.get(Medewerker.class, id);
    Gebruiker stagebedrijf = (Gebruiker)ofy.get(StageBedrijf.class, id);

    //Gebruiker instantie returnen
    if(leerling != null) {
        result = leerling;
    } else if(medewerker != null) {
        result = medewerker;
    } else if(stagebedrijf != null) {
        result = stagebedrijf;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The variables are dutch but I think you guys know the idea. The above method searches in different classes looking for a user that matches the ID and then returns it.

The problem is I get the error shown above and I'm really getting frustrated, what am I doing wrong guys? Is it the method or the way I use ID's or...?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](http://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1/javadoc/index.html) you can read for the `get` method:

> Throws: NotFoundException - if the key does not exist in the datastore

use

```
 Gebruiker leerling = (Gebruiker) ofy.find(Leerling.class, id);
```

the find method doesn't throws `NotFoundException` when the key doesn't exist but `null`.

Comment: Mateusz thank you for your answer, I think it works but it leaves me with the following problem. I get an exception 'leerling is not a supported property type' when I try to add the founded object in objectify:

CompetentieLijst cL = new CompetentieLijst(leerling, today, false);
ofy.put(cL);

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428571/objectify-appengine-embedded-class-not-a-supported-property-type). If this not help please give more details.